# uppercase greek letters in mhchem formulas gives error when compiling

Tags: errors, greek, mhchem

I tried compiling a ~1 year old document today and noticed that I got an error when using a uppercase greek letter in a chemical reaction.

Here's an MWE (with an example from the mhchem manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
$\ce{x Na(NH4)HPO4 ->[\Delta] (NaPO3)_x + x NH3 ^ + x H2O}$
\end{document}
```

It should produce: [image]

But instead gives an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...r_lower_case:f {Delta}}\prop_get:cV 
                                                  {l__chemgreek_uppercase_ma...
l.4 ...PO4 ->[\Delta] (NaPO3)_x + x NH3 ^ + x H2O}
```

I've made sure my packages are up to date:

```
Package: mhchem 2015/11/29 v4.03 for typesetting chemical formulae
```

I'm guessing this package is important:

```
Package: chemgreek 2016/01/07 v1.0d interfaceforuprightgreeklettersforuseinchemistry (CN)
```

It doesn't make any different if I load mhchem in compatibility mode (`[version=3]`).

Last time I compiled my file correctly, I had version 3.21 of mhchem and chemgreek seem to not have been used by mhchem (not loaded in log file).

```
Package: mhchem 2015/03/13 v3.21 for typesetting chemical formulae
```

Can the error be reproduced on other machines? 
Is it a known bug?
Is there a quick-fix?

---

Here's the file list as requested by @JosephWright:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  mhchem.sty    2015/11/29 v4.03 for typesetting chemical formulae
   expl3.sty    2016/01/03 v6358 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/01/03 v6358 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2015/11/11 v6250 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
l3keys2e.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
 l3regex.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 Experimental regular expressions
l3tl-build.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 Experimental token list construction
l3tl-analysis.sty    2015/11/09 v6244 L3 Experimental token lists analysis
  l3flag.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 Experimental flags
l3str-convert.sty    2015/09/26 v6106 L3 Experimental string encoding conversio
ns
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 amsmath.sty    2016/03/03 v2.15a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
chemgreek.sty    2016/01/07 v1.0d interfaceforuprightgreeklettersforuseinchemis
try (CN)
  xparse.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 Experimental document command parser
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 ***********
```

Comment: 'Works for me': you probably have an outdated file. Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit in the `File list` from the `.log` to the question.

Comment: BTW, I have `mhchem` 2016/02/07 v4.04 and `chemgreek` 2016/02/10 v1.0e.

Comment: Look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297987/mhchem-ver-4-not-working-after-update-control-sequence-undefined

Comment: @JosephWright added. Hm, you have newer versions than me..

Comment: @TobiasDK thanks for the link! Might very well be the same problem, I'll follow your instructions in the question and see

Comment: This should resolve itself with an update of your TeX distribution

Comment: This indeed is the same issue as in the linked question and [was fixed in v1.0e of `chemgreek`](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemgreek/issues/3)

Comment: @clemens, I just looked at my `chemgreek`. It was vers. 1.0d. MikTeX automatic updater could not install 1.0e, so I had to install it myself today from CTAN!

Comment: @clemens updating to 1.0e solved it as you said. I had to install it manually though, as TobiasDK reported. It did not help to use MiKTeX Update (and MiKTeX Update (Admin)). I guess version 1.0e isn't added to the repositories yet(?). Do you want to add an answer that I can accept?

Comment: Then it seems MiKTeX didn't include the new version. I sent v1.e to CTAN the same day I released the version, i.e., on 2016-02-10. How MiKTeX picks it up from CTAN I don't know.